# Can't run on dart_vlc on Flutter 2.10.4

Tags: flutter, macos, vlc

`dart_vlc` (https://github.com/alexmercerind/dart_vlc) was compiling for macOS up to now, but after upgrading to Flutter 2.10.4 I receive this error while compiling:

```
[100%] Linking CXX static library libdart_vlc_core.a
[100%] Built target dart_vlc_core
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /Users/abd/gits/myflutter/macos/Pods/../Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/dart_vlc/macos/deps/lib/libdart_vlc_core.a
error: install_name_tool: can't open file: /Users/abd/gits/myflutter/macos/Pods/VLCKit/VLCKit.xcframework/macos-arm64_x86_64/VLCKit.framework/VLCKit (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolve this-

1. **flutter clean** on a project
2. update version of dart_vlc with latest one.

Now, try to build it again and it works.